# Can you use PHP libcurl to pull files from server A to server B?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

*cURL* and *libcurl* let you do things you normally do with a browser, right? Like, as if you have a jini sit inside a server and fire up a browser and do stuff.

Ok then. I need a script to sit on server B, and *click* on download links on a server A and *download* files (from server A to server B).

I am new to curl, and not sure if all I need is to issue a simple `get` or something else. I know that `Content-disposition header` forces the browser to save the document. Does it have the same effect on libcurl too? If it does, I'll make my serving script on server A send that header, and then serve the file.

Any advice is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of curl, there's are another way

```
shell_exec ("wget http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/11396/45610/Joomla_1.5.15-Stable-Full_Package.zip");
```

Comment: thank you apris17, but i don't have access to shell_exec on either servers. and nice avatar, believe it should be a nice or similar.